# What is the average number of transactions that a BTC wallet contains?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet

If a BTC wallet has 8 addresses, and each address has 10 transactions, then that sums to 80 transactions.

Is this around the average per wallet?

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer for your question because you can not know which adresses are connected to which wallet.

By the way: You don't even need a wallet to send or receive transactions.

Comment: I thought that there would be some ballpark number, we can assume that not everyone sends 10,00 transactions a day.

I was thinking that the ballpark would be around 200 as a average, with the outliers going as high as 4k, as you said there is no answer for the question however.

Thanks Alpha for asnwering! :)

Answer (score 0):

a bitcoin wallet has no transactions, that are stored. A bitcoin wallet is basically a key container. These keys are stored, along with some management information, not the transactions (which are in the blockchain).

In very early versions of bitcoin core (and probably other wallets), there were some keys "pre generated", to have enough addresses for transactions (for privacy reasons you were asked to change the sending/receiving address for each transaction). This made the backup concept a bit difficult. Nowadays most wallets are HD wallets, which can derive 2^31 keys from a priv/public keypair (master keys or master public keys).